# Template classes & template functions : Point & Euclidean distance

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

I need help understanding why my program won't work. I have a feeling that the problem lurks in my badly-written template function, and I want to correct it.

The Point class is initialized by writing something like:

```
Point<int, 2> p1; //where int is the type and 2 is the dimension (in this case 2d)
```

In my main function I initialize points and add values to each value in the Point array (ex. p1.arr[0] = 3; which would be like x = 3) and then I try to use my function and print it out, but the program wouldn't open up anything and the compiler wouldn't say what the error is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, int n>
class Point
{
public:
    int dimen = n;
    T arr[n];
    Point<>(){};
};

template<typename A>
double euclidean_distance(A a, A b){
    double k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.dimen; ++i){ //neglecting the fact that a and b may be of
        double op = (b.arr[i] - a.arr[i]); //different dimensions
        k += pow(op, 2);
    }
    return sqrt(k);
}
```

The Euclidean distance equation is based on the dimensions of the two points being analyzed:

In 2-dimensional space: sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)

In 3-dimensional space: sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2 )

Comment: So what is the problem? BTW you don't need to store the point's dimension in each point object. You can use a static data member for that.

Comment: to be honest, you don't even need a member, it's part of the type. Anyway, a question would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Point` syntax is incorrect. You probably want it to look like:

```
template<typename T, int n>
struct Point
{
    static const int dimen = n;
    T arr[n];
    Point(){}; // <== note: no <>
};
```

In your actual `euclidean_distance` method, `a` and `b` actually cannot be of different dimensions because the number of dimensions is part of the type and both of those objects are of the same type, `A`.

With the change to make `dimen` a `static const`, you could change your loop to be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A::dimen; ++i) {
```

Or explicitly make your function only take `Point`s:

```
template <typename T, int DIM>
double euclidean_distance(const Point<T,DIM>& a,
                          const Point<T,DIM>& b)
{
    double k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; ++i) {
       // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, OP's code shoud "work" without modifications.

Comment: @juanchopanza At the very least, the constructor is wrong. And I'm not sure OP is using C++11, so `dimen` declaration is probably wrong too.